# Firing Tags when a Virtual Page View occured

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We've created a multistep form and added virtual page views for the steps and confirmation page. Is there a way to use these virtual page views in Tag Manager to fire some tags?

In Google Tag Assistant I do see the pageviews being tracked in Analytics, but the tags aren't fired when I used these pageviews to be the trigger.

The virtual page views are hardcoded, not done through Tag Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual page views is a virtual concept :) Depending on how it is implemented:

- **If URL doesn't change**: you need to [push events to the `dataLayer`](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#multipush). [Here is an example](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/).
- **If URL changes**: you can use the built-in [`History Change`](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679322?hl=en) trigger. [Here is an example](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/single-page-web-app-with-google-tag-manager/).