# How to import GA Ecommerce Shopping Behavior Analysis Data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets-api

I would like to create a Report in Google Sheets using the Google Analytics API - more precisely, to import the data in Ecommerce Shopping Behavior Analysis.

Specifically, the following data appears unavailable as a metric / dimension:

**- No Cart Addition
 - Sessions with Add to Cart
 - Cart Abandonment
 - Sessions with Check-Out
 - Check-Out Abandonment**

I also noticed that Product Add to Carts and Quantity Add to Cart (in metrics) does not present the data as unique - i.e. unique Add to Carts within a session but rather the total Add to Carts for a given dimension.

Brief, how can I access information available in Ecommerce Shopping Behaviour Data in GA via a Google Analytics API / Report in Google Sheets.

Comment: Have you checked on [Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce)? And [this discussion from the help forum](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014872?hl=en)?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [list of dimensions and metrics available in the core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

**Unfortunately, you cannot fetch cart abandonment data as is**, because there are no dimensions and metrics about it and the API doesn't expose the various e-commerce checkout steps (it's something calculated internally by GA, but not exposed via the API).

Your options:

- **Cart Abandonment Segment**: you can create a segment ([UI](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en), [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#segments)) which conditions reflect that of an abandoned cart. For instance people who added something to their cart but ended up not buying (`ga:productAddsToCart>0 AND ga:transactionRevenue=0`) and apply that segment to your API requests so all the data you pull is related to abandonments.

[image]

- **Goal Abandonment metric**: you can configure an additional [funnel goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en#funnels_for_destination_goals) with each step matching a page of your funnel (if you have a one-page checkout, you will need to setup [virtual pageviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372843/firing-tags-when-a-virtual-page-view-occured/50374587#50374587) you can use in your funnel), and use the `ga:goalXXAbandonRate` or `ga:goalXXAbandons` metrics to get the number of abandons.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. The best way to thank me is to upvote and accept my answer :)